# Link de imagem com JavaScript não funciona

Tags: javascript, funções

Ok, eu sei que existem milhares de maneiras de fazer isso(melhores e mais fáceis) mas eu apenas gostaria de fazer isso funcionar. Estou passando as imagens através do JS e gostaria de atribuir o link da mesma, porém, não funciona... O console não retorna erro algum, alguem poderia ajudar ?

```
window.onload = function(){
    rdSocial = $("#social");

    var fb = '<img src="img/fb.png" value="1" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';
    var twt = '<img src="img/twitter.png" value="2" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';
    var insta = '<img src="img/insta.png" value="3" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';

    rdSocial.innerHTML += fb;
    rdSocial.innerHTML += twt;
    rdSocial.innerHTML += insta;
}

function redireciona(obj){
    if(obj.value == "1"){
        window.location="#";
    }
}
```

Comment: Acredito que a atribuição não funciona pois o seu rdSocial é um objeto JQuery; Se você trocar `rdSocial.innerHTML += fb;` por `rdSocial.html(fb);` ou trocar seu `rdSocial = $("#social");` por `document.getElementbyID('social');` vai funcionar....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a misturar alguns conceitos:

- jQuery e JavaScript nativo

Usar `$('#social')` vai dar-te um objeto jQuery e não um elemento do DOM onde possas usar `.innerHTML`. Ou mudas para nativo usando `.getElementById(id)` ou mudar para jQuery e usas `.html(conteudo)`

- `value` não é uma propriedade de imagens

O elemento `<img>` nõ tem por natureza `value`. Assim ele é lido como atributo e para o ires buscar tens de usar `img.getAttribute('value')`.

Sugestão: faz isso com código nativo:

```
window.onload = function(){
    rdSocial = document.getElementById("social");

    var fb = '<img src="img/fb.png" value="1" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';
    var twt = '<img src="img/twitter.png" value="2" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';
    var insta = '<img src="img/insta.png" value="3" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';

    rdSocial.innerHTML += fb;
    rdSocial.innerHTML += twt;
    rdSocial.innerHTML += insta;
}

function redireciona(el){
    var value = el.getAttribute('value');
    if(value == "1"){
        window.location="#";
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu !

Comment: @GabrielOzzy Que bom que a resposta do Sergio te ajudou! Estava olhando o seu perfil, e reparei que você não deu nenhum voto no site ainda (exceto os de aceitação). Sugiro dar uma revisada nas suas perguntas e votar também em outras respostas que possam ter te ajudado (pode votar também nas que aceitou). Se você encontrar perguntas de outras pessoas que te parecem úteis, vote nelas também! O site está precisando de mais votos, eles são fundamentais para a organização do conteúdo, para separar o joio do trigo. Obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @bfavaretto ! Eu não me atentei a isso, e estamos numa comunidade aonde temos que ajudar para ser ajudados, sempre ! Ser mais um a apontar um bom caminho é sempre bom ! Seguirei o conselho ! Obrigado pelo toque !